# Error when trying to access an object inside an array with React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to access a property on an array that has on index 0 an object and I'm trying the following: `object[0].main` But the console throws me an error.

I'm using React on codepen so it doesn't show me the error pretty well, I want to access that property to be able to put it on another object that I'll pass down as props (because is something I hold on my state). Here is my code: https://codepen.io/manAbl/pen/aGymRg?editors=0011 Look for line 56.
This is stressing me out. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the data is not loaded from the server yet so the object will be initially as you set it to {}

so to fix this you can do

instead of

```
description: this.state.weather.weather[0].main,
```

do

```
description: this.state.weather.weather && this.state.weather.weather[0].main,
```

The idea is you set the initial state to : {} correct? and render is called before the ajax is actually finished since its async.

so on first render it will be "{}" and you are doing [0].main on it. which will crash.

Comment: Can you explain me how that code works? Like with pseudo-code or with your own words

Comment: Updated answer.